Have I been exposed by using “python http.server?”
I know there are a lot of threads about Python's http.server, but I have a very simple question to that I could not find an answer. I ran python -m http.server without any flags or options.
I was expecting to open a server that only listens to 127.0.0.1, but instead it listened to ::, which seems to be IPv6 for 0.0.0.0. So, if I got that right, my folder was accessible from the LAN. Was it also accessible from the web?
Have I been exposed and why does it not per default only listen to 127.0.0.1?

Does that PC have a public IP address? If not, e.g., the average home installation, then no.

It’s a private Mac with Sequoia 15.1.1, so I guess not. However, I’m connected to a cabled company network. Have to ask for their config.

Unless you've specifically requested (and usually, paid extra for) a public IP address from your ISP, the outside world cannot connect to your server. See https://superuser.com/questions/1310355/how-to-make-my-ip-address-a-public-web-address

There are a lot of details to clarify regarding your situation, but here are some general thoughts.
You have been exposed insomuch as your firewall / router / edge device allows incoming traffic on IPv6 port 80, as well as the host running the service allows incoming traffic on that port.  If you don't allow incoming traffic, and if you have a firewall running on the host running the http server then I doubt you have been exposed very much at all.
As to why it doesn't listen only to localhost by default - well, because that's how it's implemented.  The documentation states quite clearly that it is not recommended for production and only implements basic security checks:

This starts to get into opinion oriented things so I won't go far with this, but it's usually easier to just listen on everything during development.

I am connected to a cabled network at work/university outside of their core network. Need to find out more about their config/firewall. I hope macOS firewall gave additional security. And yes, I didn’t want to use it for productive purposes. Just needed an url to a local file for JavaScript for testing. The server was only online for a few minutes. Guess I’ll find another way for that or can I force it to only listen to 127.0.0.1 only?

@gernophil - If you allowed the web traffic on the port then the firewall did very little.

By allowed you mean on my Mac or in the config of the university network?

And also, would I have seen any connection attempt in my terminal window? Because there wasn’t any.

@gernophil Read the documentation for http.server.  You can bind it to any address and any port your system allows you to.  My comment about using it during development was to explain that it makes sense to just let it run wide open by default instead of trying to force a developer to mess with ports and addresses.  And you would not have received a notification of any connection attempt in a terminal window.  You would have to look at logs for that, if they're enabled.

@gernophil I'm not saying there's no chance that something tried to connect during that couple of minutes you had the http server running.  But the chances that anything did and had time to do anything with what you would have exposed are extremely slim.

Talked to our IT and they said, the used network is not visible from the outside :). Still gonna accept this answer as a warning to everyone else.
